# NodeJS JSON.stringify() bottleneck

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stringify

My service returns responses of very large JSON objects - around 60MB. After some profiling I have found that it spends almost all of the time doing the `JSON.stringify()` call which is used to convert to string and send it as a response. I have tried custom implementations of stringify and they are even slower.

This is quite a bottleneck for my service. I want to be able to handle as many requests per second as possible - currently 1 request takes 700ms.

My questions are:
1) Can I optimize the sending of response part? Is there a more effective way than stringify-ing the object and sending the response?

2) Will using async module and performing the `JSON.stringify()` in a separate thread improve overall the number of requests/second(given that over 90% of the time is spent at that call)?

Comment: There's nothing you can do to reduce the size of those objects? What's making them so big?

Comment: Did you try using socket.io. JSON.stringify loads the entire object into memory so I dont think you can optimize it. But 60 mb of json is just too huge.

Comment: Are you sending redundant data? If a subset of your data is modified, don't resend all the data, just resend the subset. That might allow you to reduce the amount of data you stringify

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you are using to send the response so we can assess your process.

Comment: How are you consuming this service.. i.e. Do you have to serialize it as JSON? Maybe try serializing and sending as BSON instead? I would imagine you'd see a performance improvement encoding/decoding it; and the output should be smaller.

Comment: @Reinard Mavronicolas I am thinking of using https://github.com/kesla/node-snappy to compress the json directly thus avoiding the JSON.stringify() call. What do you think? Will report back with the results.

Comment: @gosho_ot_pochivka by the looks of it you'll have to compress your objects and then decompress it to get JSON; sounds like overhead to me. But it would be interesting to see the results.

Comment: I've had a similar situation happen. My solution may not be applicable but if it is I hope it helps. My master json object's first level consisted of 9 different sub objects. Instead of requesting the master object, I sent 9 requests for the 9 sub objects. It decreased my wait time dramatically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got two options:

1) find a JSON module that will allow you to stream the stringify operation, and process it in chunks.  I don't know if such a module is out there, if it's not you'd have to build it. **EDIT:** Thanks to Reinard Mavronicolas for pointing out [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) in the comments.  I've actually had it on my back burner to look for something like this, for a different use case.

2) `async` does not use threads.  You'd need to use `cluster` or some other actual threading module to drop the processing into a separate thread.  The caveat here is that you're still processing a large amount of data, you're gaining bandwidth using threads but depending on your traffic you still may hit a limit.

Comment: thanks! I have another idea - to gzip the content and make my service return gziped conent instead. I found this library https://github.com/sapienlab/jsonpack which provides function which takes the json object and returns the gzipped string and it seems to me that it doesn't internally call JSON.stringify(). What do you think?

Comment: As long as it does streamed/evented/chunked processing, that's probably fine.  Dealing with that much data all in one operation without breaking it up into pieces is going to take a long time no matter what you do with it.

Comment: @Jason, you can add to your answer under point number 1 - https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream. Also, seems to be anohter SO question similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503844/streaming-piping-json-stringify-output-in-node-js-express

Comment: streaming to msgpack would probably be even better.

Answer (score 8):

After some year, this question has a new answer for the first question: [yieldable-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yieldable-json) lib.
As described by in [this talk by Gireesh Punathil (IBM India)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQi7P0f-DXk), this lib can evaluate a JSON of 60MB without blocking the event loop of node.js let you accept new requests in order to upgrade your throughput.

For the second one, with [node.js 11 in the experimental phase](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads), you can use the worker thread in order to increase your web server throughput.

Comment: Did you implement either of those? I am experimenting with yieldable-json, worker threads and even a native API extension like https://github.com/lemire/simdjson

Comment: Yes, I used `yieldable-json` but I didn't try other approaches