# Avoiding Node.js event loop block while running JSON.stringify

Tags: json, node.js, serialization, stringify

I have a huge data structure that I need to dump to file:

```
fs.writeFile('dump.json', JSON.stringify(bigData));
```

The resulting file is close to 100MB and it takes several seconds to generate. While `JSON.stringify` runs, it blocks the event loop and my server does not handle any requests.

Is there a way to somehow split the `JSON.stringify` call? My `bigData` var is an array of objects, so I could probably write a function to serialize them separately and then stitch the JSON together, to make sure that requests can be handled in between - but are there any solutions that are already existing (external modules is fine)?

Answer (score 0):

Try [stream-json-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json-stringify). It should do the trick.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10412107)

Comment: @AhmedAshour - you cannot seriously expect the whole module source to be pasted in the answer. The link is to the module's homepage, and that is just fine.

Comment: As for the module itself, it writes some data, but not all - I get only some 50MB instead of all 100MB of data. Quite hard to trace what's missing though!

Comment: I'm new here. Don't know the rules yet. Just wanted to help.
Anyway, if there is a bug or an issue in the package, why not send a message to the owner? (For you and for the sake of others that will use this package in the future).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I found code at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13504078/979 which seems to work.